# Best (NoSQL?) DB for small docs/records, unchanging data, lots of writes, quick reads?

Tags: sql, nosql

I found a few questions in the same vein as this, but they did not include much detail on the nature of the data being stored, how it is queried, etc... so I thought this would be worthwhile to post.

My data is very simple, three fields: 
- a "datetimestamp" value (date/time)
- two strings, "A" and "B", both < 20 chars

My application is very write-heavy (hundreds per second). All writes are new records; once inserted, the data is never modified.

Regular reads happen every few seconds, and are used to populate some near-real-time dashboards. I query against the date/time value and one of the string values. e.g. get all records where the datetimestamp is within a certain range and field "B" equals a specific search value.  These queries typically return a few thousand records each.

Lastly, my database does not need to grow without limit; I would be looking at purging records that are 10+ days old either by manually deleting them or using a cache-expiry technique if the DB supported one.

I initially implemented this in MongoDB, without being aware of the way it handles locking (writes block reads). As I scale, my queries are taking longer and longer (30+ seconds now, even with proper indexing). Now with what I've learned, I believe that the large number of writes are starving out my reads.

I've read the [kkovacs.eu](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis) post comparing various NoSQL options, and while I learned a lot I don't know if there is a clear winner for my use case. I would greatly appreciate a recommendation from someone familiar with the options.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you recording that you need hundreds of writes per second to populate a db for real-time dashboards?

Comment: @eaolson I'm recording events as they occur, and I have no control over the input coming to me. The two strings identify a "what" and a "where".  The queries are mostly things like "select all of the events at location [x] in the past 5 minutes".  The results are cached and combined with the results from earlier queries (from previous time-slices), and plotted on the dashboard.

Comment: I would suggest you rethink whether you need to record all this data in a database. Could you aggregate, say, 100 ms of data and store only the aggregate? Per @ValBakhtin, I believe SQLite locks the entire database file while writing, which sounds like it would make it unsuitable for this app.

Comment: Do you query against both A and B or just B? And is time always part of the query, i.e can you have a query which does not have time? Likewise are there queries which have only time? Are the values that A/B can take fixed?

Comment: Ok so far I understand you need to write data very fast

How frequent are the select query's executed? like on the fly on some refresh timer/daly/weekly,...?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a problem like this before in a system recording process control measurements.  This was done with 5 MHz IBM PCs, so it is definitely possible.  The use cases were more varied—summarization by minute, hour, eight-hour-shift, day, week, month, or year—so the system recorded all the raw data, but is also aggregated on the fly for the most common queries (which were five minute averages).  In the case of your dashboard, it seems like five minute aggregation is also a major goal.

Maybe this could be solved by writing a pair of text files for each input stream:  One with all the raw data; another with the multi-minute aggregation.  The dashboard would ignore the raw data.  A database could be used, of course, to do the same thing.  But simplifying the application could mean no RDB is needed.  Simpler to engineer and maintain, easier to fit on a microcontroller, embedded system, etc., or a more friendly neighbor on a shared host.

Answer (score 0):

Deciding a right NoSQL product is not an easy task. I would suggest you to learn more about NoSQL before making your choice, if you really want to make sure that you don't end up trusting someone else's suggestion or favorites.

There is a good book which gives really good background about NoSQL and anyone who is starting up with NoSQL should read this.

[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-NoSQL-Wrox-Programmer/dp/047094224X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047094224X)

I hope reading some of the chapters in the book will really help you. There are comparisons and explanations about what is good for what job and lot more.

Good luck.